# how to convert OX12 to decimal

Tags: java, numbers, hex, decimal, converters

I need to convert hexadecimal value which is OX12 to decimal in JAVA,

as I knew hexadecimal is based 16 (1..9, a..f), but in this case, I don't know how to convert with that value.

Can someone help me?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

If the number is a `String`, you can use the `parseInt` method of the `Integer` class with first argument `"12"` (the number in hex) and second argument `16`, the radix, or base, of the number

```java
int number = Integer.parseInt("12", 16);
System.out.println(number);
// output is 18
```

If the number is not a `String`, you can simply do the following:

```java
int number = 0x12;
System.out.println(number);
// output is 18
```